# GetJSON not working with PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to use the getJSON function with a PHP file that echo some JSON. If I save the JSON expected from the PHP file as a JSON file, it works perfect but if I use the PHP file as URL it doesn't work because it fails when parsing the PHP at line 1 column 1.

PHP file:

```
<?php

$jsondata = array();

if( isset($_GET['param']) ) {

if( $_GET['param'] == 'valor' ) {
    $jsondata['success'] = true;
    $jsondata['message'] = 'Correct.';
} else {
    $jsondata['success'] = false;
    $jsondata['message'] = 'Incorrect.';
}
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($jsondata);
exit();
}

?>
```

And this is what I am using in the Javascript file:

```
    $.getJSON('test.php', {format: "json"}, function(data) {
        window.alert("Loaded");
    }).fail( function(data, textStatus, error) {
        console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
    });
```

If I change from test.php to test.json it works.

**EDIT: I was using mysql instead of mysqli and the server outputted a table and then my JSON and thats why I had the JSON Error parse ... 
Fixed just changing from mysql to mysqli.
Thanks everyone.**

Comment: `PHP file: (php tag not showing, don't know why)` what does this mean?

Comment: The header of any php file not showing here on SO but I have it on my file.

Comment: I edited it for you.

Comment: Are you sure that you have PHP running on your server?  What do you get if you request the test.php file through your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( $_GET['param'] == 'valor' ) {
    $row = array('success'=> true,'message'=>'Correct');
    array_push($jsondata,$row);
} else {
    $row = array('success'=> false,'message'=>'Incorrect');
    array_push($jsondata,$row);
}
```

And the echo remains the same:

```
echo json_encode($jsondata);
```

I've coded like this when I had to work with JSON and PHP with JQuery.I hope it works for you too.

Comment: I keep getting the same error:
getJSON failed, status: parsererror, error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I guess the problem is because getJSON reads literally the PHP instead of reading the echo json_encode...

Comment: Are you trying to add any words with any accentuation on your JSON?
If so, you need to encode you string, JQuery only accepts UTF-8 strings. You need to use: `utf8_encode("Word with accentuation")`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.